# Chaining configSource within configuration files

Tags: configuration, web-config, configsource

Is it possible to 'nest' configSourced configuration? I receive an error: 'Unrecognized attribute 'configSource'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.'

**Folder structure:**

```
Root Folder
Config
    EnvironmentConfiguration
        DistributedCalls.config
    UmbracoSettings.config  
web.config
```

**Web.config**

```
<umbracoConfiguration>
    <settings configSource="config\umbracoSettings.config" />
....
</umbracoConfiguration>
```

**umbracoSettings.config**

```
...
<distributedCall configSource="EnvironmentConfigurations\DistributedCalls.config" />
...
```

**DistributedCalls.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Used by umbracoSettings.config --> 
<distributedCall enable="false">
```